# C# Getting a component's values at runtime?

Tags: c#, winforms, components, notifyicon

I'm attempting to create a NotifyIcon that can be inherited so that I can add my own properties/etc. Through looking at a component class someone else wrote, I've made some progress as can be seen below, and the component can be dragged into the form. To be honest, I have little idea on what I'm doing, and there appears to be no tutorials anywhere on the internet that are of any use at all.

In the `PrepareIcon` method you see, the message box that pops up appears blank, even though I have tried changing the value from the designer default of `notifyIconInheritable1`. I have seen the NotifyIcon appear while in the designer, so I have been utterly confused on how this works.

The question is; what's wrong with this or what am I doing wrong, and am I wasting my time and shouldn't be attempting this at all?

```
namespace AwesomeNotifyIcon
{
    [DefaultProperty("Text"), DefaultEvent("Click"), Description("Displays an icon in the notification area, on the right side of the Windows taskbar, during run time")]
    public partial class NotifyIconInheritable : Component
    {
        private NotifyIcon notifyIcon;

        public NotifyIconInheritable()
        {
            //PrepareIcon();
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        public NotifyIconInheritable(IContainer container)
        {
            if (container != null)
            {
                container.Add(this);
            }
            PrepareIcon();
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        [Category("Appearance"), Description("The icon to associate with the balloon ToolTip."), DefaultValue(ToolTipIcon.None)]
        public ToolTipIcon BalloonTipIcon { get; set; }

        [Category("Appearance"), Description("The text to associate with the balloon ToolTip.")]
        public string BalloonTipText { get; set; }

        [Category("Appearance"), Description("The title of the balloon ToolTip.")]
        public string BalloonTipTitle { get; set; }

        [Category("Appearance"), Description("The icon to display in the system tray.")]
        public Icon Icon { get; set; }

        [Category("Appearance"), Description("The text that will be displayed when the mouse hovers over the icon.")]
        public string Text { get; set; }

        [Category("Behaviour"), Description("The shortcut menu to show when the user right-clicks the icon.")]
        public ContextMenuStrip ContextMenuStrip { get; set; }

        [Category("Behaviour"), Description("Determines whether the control is visible or hidden."), DefaultValue(false)]
        public bool Visible { get; set; }

        [Category("Data"), Description("User-defined data associated with the object.")]
        public object Tag { get; set; }

        [Category("Action"), Description("Occurs when the component is clicked.")]
        public event EventHandler Click;

        private void PrepareIcon()
        {
            notifyIcon = new NotifyIcon();
            notifyIcon.Dispose();
            MessageBox.Show(this.Text);

            if (Click != null)
                notifyIcon.Click += Click;
        }
    }
}
```

Here's the properties as seen in the designer:

[http://cl.ly/1vIF/content http://cl.ly/1vIF/content](http://cl.ly/1vIF/content)

Comment: I'm sorry, but what exactly is your question?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you add a control using the designer, it generates code that looks something like this:

```
NotifyIconInheritable icon = new NotifyIconInheritable();
icon.Text = "Some text";
parent.Controls.Add(icon);
```

You can see that your property isn't set until *after* the constructor has run.  So, at the point when you call `PrepareIcon`, the `Text` really is null.

Other advice: as Henk says, you really shouldn't be calling `Dispose()` at this point in your code.  You also shouldn't be showing a message box from a constructor, though hopefully that's just there for your testing purposes.  Finally, because you're calling `PrepareIcon` from the constructor, `.Click` will always be `null`.

Comment: More importantly, any designer generated code is added to the component's `InitializeComponent` method.  He should safely be able to call `PrepareIcon` after that method call.

Comment: Moving `PrepareIcon()` to after `InitializeComponent()` didn't seem to change the output of the message box.

Comment: You're not thinking about the bigger picture.  the `InitializeComponent` method is for the current component, setting any child control properties in the designer, the changes to those child controls will happen here.  The instance of your `NotifyIconInheritable` is added to another control the next level up in your control tree, and its in that parent control's `InitializeComponent` method where the `Text` property is set.

Comment: So in this instance, moving `PrepareIcon` after **this** control's `InitializeComponent` method is still getting it called before the property is set.

What you may want to consider is moving the `PrepareIcon` call to somewhere later in the controls event lifecycle, possible before `OnPaint` or somewhere near?

Comment: Does a component have an `OnPaint` event?

Comment: ^ LOL, good point, no it doesn't. Er, he still needs to defer that method call possibly outside the initialisation code altogether, or possibly make his `NotifyIconInheritable` a `Control` that doesn't paint anything?

Comment: I'm starting to think perhaps I should just create some extension methods and as for events just have some dodgy extension method like `notifyIcon.AddBlahEventCallback(notifyIcon_OnBlah)`

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do?  It's unusual to wire up an eventhandler in the constructor in the way you are anyway - what behaviour are you looking for?